# Threads_running is always one Mariadb 10.5

Tags: mariadb, cpu

Maria DB which is installed on linux server, always shows the Threads_running one , while we have 4 core of cpu .We changed thread_handling to pool of threads , but still no result , while we have concurrent connection reaches to 500.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Threads running always shows 1 on 4 core cpu ,while Threads_connected are 400 , during high load

Answer (score 0):

`Threads_running` is the number of connections currently running an SQL query.

To read `Threads_running`, you must perform one query.  That will be the "1" you are seeing.

The number of CPU cores is not relevant; one query will either be using one core, or it will be waiting for a core to be available.  In either case, it counts as one `Threads_running`.

The thread pool is a collection of threads (processes) created for MariaDB by the OS.  MariaDB holds onto several threads so the that next request (from a client) to connect will get started a little bit faster.  This is not relevant to `Threads_running`.

Running `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` usually shows a long list of "Sleep" connections doing nothing, plus one connection doing that `SHOW`.  Similarly, if you do

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Threads_running';
```

(This answer applies to all(?) versions of MySQL and MariaDB.)